# How to collect billing address through Stripe Payment Request Button

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating a payment request like this:

```
const paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
    country: config.stripeCountry,
    currency: config.currency,
    total: {
      label: 'Total',
      amount: parseInt((paymentAmounts.totalAmount * 100).toFixed())
    },
    requestShipping: true,
    requestPayerEmail: true,
    requestPayerName: true,
    // It seems this one is not working
    shippingOptions: config.shippingOptions
  })
```

Now I'd like to collect a customer's billing address. But the doc says:

> **Requesting the payer’s name, email, or phone** is optional, but highly
>   recommended, as **it also results in collecting their billing address
>   for Apple Pay**. The billing address can be used to perform address
>   verification and block fraudulent payments. For all other payment
>   methods, the billing address is automatically collected when
>   available.

So how shall I collect their billing address with the payer's name, email or phone?

Answer (score 0):

For Apple Pay, requesting one of name, email, or phone (which you're already doing via `requestPayerEmail` and `requestPayerName`) triggers billing address to be collected. For other payment methods, you don't have to do anything.

In other words, you're all set as-is.

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-payment-request

> We highly recommend you collect at least one of name, email, or phone as this also results in collection of billing address for Apple Pay. The billing address can be used to perform address verification and block fraudulent payments. For all other payment methods, the billing address is automatically collected when available.